# Uninstall drivers through command line

Tags: powershell, psexec

TLDR: How do I automate uninstall of all drivers in two categories without needing to know the OEM number beforehand?

---

First things first - I'm as far from an expert as they come. I'm an L1 support desk grunt messing with powershell to try automate the tedious parts of my job. A persistent issue we've got with 90% of our machines requires uninstalling all drivers for audio devices, and because I'm too lazy to do this in a remote session, I'm trying to automate it through a script that fires off a bunch of commands through psexec to a specified hostname.

Downside is driver name is not always going to be the same on each machine, and the OEM number for the drivers isn't consistent across multiple machines either. This doesn't matter when you're doing it through device manager - just need to uninstall everything in the Audio I/O and Sound Controllers dropdown - but I've no idea how to specify this in command line.

I'm sure it's possible. I've been poking around at pnputil and Get-WindowsDriver and there's gotta be some way to do it. Might be something with wmic that could work, but I'm not familiar enough with that command. I could just do it manually, but then I'd have to spend five minutes in a laggy remote session making small talk with a user, and I can't *stand* small talk.

So essentially my question is: Is there a way to query OEM info of every driver in a specific category, and then pipe that info into a cmdlet that'll uninstall them?

Comment: Are you just removing the device from Device manager, or actually uninstalling all the drivers one at a time?

Comment: Uninstalling the device - not deleting the original drivers.